# R: ncol returning a NULL even though object is a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix that has only one column whose elements aren't entirely 0.

I use the following code to get the number of non-zero columns in a matrix:

```
ncol(matrix[, colSums(matrix) != 0])
```

This code returns the right number when the matrix has MORE than 1 non-zero column, but when the matrix has exactly 1 non-zero column, this code returns NULL.

I tried using this code and it seems to work fine:

```
length(which(colSums(matrix) != 0))
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `drop = FALSE`, otherwise `[` will reduce its result to a vector if there is only one column.

```
ncol(matrix[, colSums(matrix) != 0, drop = FALSE])
```

Or just use `NCOL`, which accounts for this possibility.

```
NCOL(matrix[, colSums(matrix) != 0])
```